# How to read tag no from HID iClass reader in serial port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port, hid

I am in project where I want to read the HID iclass reader to read the CARD Number through serial port where i am getting **" 0 0 0 0 "**  in received serial port. can someone help me to solve the issue.

```
 // My Event Handler Method
    private static void port_OnReceiveDatazz(object sender,
                               SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
        byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead];
        Console.WriteLine("DATA RECEIVED!");
        spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        string S = Encoding.Default.GetString(buf);
        Console.Write("EncodingByte:" + S);
        //foreach (Byte b in buf)
        //{
            
        //    Console.Write(b.ToString());
        //}
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Please let me know what can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code, I suspect that your problem lies outside of this event handler. The only thing that comes to mind is to check the baud rate, parity, and port in your constructor and to validate that your sent data is correct for your hardware. You might try to test your reads and writes with Putty or some other serial port interface first before you write code around it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. but problem is that in putty I am unable to read anything with comport selection. , on screen nothing is visible
if I changed baud rate to 9600 data received event is not triggering.

Comment: First get working with putty which easier to debug issue.  Is device a USB or regular serial port.  Sound like it maybe USB.  Check in Device Manager the driver.  Make sure you are using the vendor USB driver and not the standard Microsoft USB driver.  The default driver is the Microsoft which doesn't work with most vendors USB interfaces.

Comment: Yes its USB and using vendor drivers. in putty its showing one lie now. but not in readable format, I set baud rate to 115200 in putty